# Custom Drawable for ProgressDialog

Tags: android, android-xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360">

    <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:thicknessRatio="8" android:useLevel="false">

        <size android:width="48dip" android:height="48dip" />

        <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
            android:startColor="#4c737373" android:centerColor="#4c737373"
            android:centerY="0.50" android:endColor="#ffffd300" />

    </shape>

</rotate>
```

This code creates a circle indicator and it will rotate it to show one color but I want it instead to display multi-colors.

Comment: multi color?  what exactly?

Comment: right now indicator color is blue but i want blue in first rotate after color should be green third time rotate color should red above code display only one color for all the time is it possible to do ???

Comment: how ?? i don't  know how to crate you have any example and can  that used  in this code